# Multiple Conditions for CoolURI in Typo3 7.6.10

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I currently have some problems using CoolURI (yes, I know, please no debate about RealURL being the better choice – I have to use it).

I wonder if there could be some sort of syntax to use multiple parameters at once.

For example:

```
<part>
            <parameter>tx_funky-extension[id]</parameter>
            <t3conv>1</t3conv>
</part>
```

combined with

```
<part>
            <parameter>tx_funky-extension[userID]</parameter>
            <t3conv>1</t3conv>
</part>
```

so only if both parameters show up, this condition will be used.

Any Idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a userFunction for that purpose, you will have access to some configuration there, maybe you can access other parameters too.

```
<part>
    <parameter>tx_funky-extension[id]</parameter>
    <userfunc>Vendor\FunkyExtension\UserFunc\SomeClassName->getUrlPart</userfunc>
</part>
```